# Did Not receive a recall notice for sticky dashboard. Will Toyota still fix it?

Tags: toyota, camry, recall

Did not receive a recall notice for sticky dashboard on my 2010 Toyota Camry. It was in husband`s name at that time. Will they still fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I had a "notice to repair" from Mazda for my ~30 year old, Jap-import 1990 Familia.  Dealer fixed it for free, just had to book the time.

Answer (score 3):

If there is an actual recall for your vehicle, it will be against the VIN in the Toyota computers. If you take your vehicle into a Toyota dealership, they will run your VIN to see if the recall exists against it and will fix it for you if it comes up. It really doesn't matter if you received a notice or not. It doesn't matter if you were the owner of the vehicle when the recall came out (or if it wasn't in your name), Toyota (or any manufacturer for that matter) will honor the recall if it hasn't been completed on the vehicle already.

**NOTE:** If you take it in and they say it needs the recall, they may need to order parts or whatever. Don't expect them to fix it "Johnny On The Spot", as they may not be able to do it right away. They *will* honor it, though.

Comment: +1. I had a faulty Takata driver's airbag in my 2011 Toyota Yaris. They did not bother contacting me, and when I took my car for the next service, they told me about the recall. So, not all recalls will mean the manufacturer will contact the owner.

Comment: @juhist there are very few recalls that the manufacturers have been forced to proactively search and find ALL vehicles to effect a change - usually on safety grounds. Most are done on an ad hoc basis as vehicles come into a registered dealer / service shop.